Next.js 14: undefined Value Error When Serializing products in getServerSideProps
I'm using Next.js 14.2.3 and attempting to fetch a list of products from Firestore using the getProducts function from @stripe/firestore-stripe-payments in getServerSideProps. However, I'm encountering a serialization error:

Server Error
Error: Error serializing .products returned from getServerSideProps in "/".
Reason: undefined cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use null or omit this value.

Here is the relevant part of my code:
import Head from "next/head";
import Header from "@/components/Header";
import Banner from "@/components/Banner";
import { Movie } from "@/typings";
import requests from "@/utils/requests";
import Row from "@/components/Row";
import useAuth from "@/hooks/useAuth";
import { useRecoilValue } from "recoil";
import { modalState } from "@/atoms/moduleAtom";
import Modal from "@/components/Modal";
import Plans from "@/components/Plans";
import { Product, getProducts } from "@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments";
import payments from "@/lib/stripe";

interface Props {
netflixOriginals: Movie[];
trendingNow: Movie[];
topRated: Movie[];
actionMovies: Movie[];
comedyMovies: Movie[];
horrorMovies: Movie[];
romanceMovies: Movie[];
documentaries: Movie[]
products: Product[]
}

const Home = ({
netflixOriginals,
actionMovies,
comedyMovies,
documentaries,
horrorMovies,
romanceMovies,
topRated,
trendingNow,
products
Props) => {
console.log(products)
const { logout, loading } = useAuth()
const showModal = useRecoilValue(modalState)
const subscription = false


if (loading || subscription === null) return 
null

if (!subscription) return <Plans/>


return (
    <div
this is so we cant scroll when we open the modal
className={`relative h-screen bg-gradient-to-b lg:h-[140vh] ${showModal && "!h-screen overflow-hidden"}`}
    >
      <Head>
        <title>Home - Netflix</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Header />
      <main className="relative pl-4 pb-24 lg:space-y24 lg:pl-16">
        <Banner netflixOriginals={netflixOriginals}/>
        <section className="md:space-y-24">
        <Row title="Trending Now" movies={trendingNow} />
          <Row title="Top Rated" movies={topRated} />
          <Row title="Action Thrillers" movies={actionMovies} />
My List Component*/}
          <Row title="Comedies" movies={comedyMovies} />
          <Row title="Scary Movies" movies={horrorMovies} />
          <Row title="Romance Movies" movies={romanceMovies} />
          <Row title="Documentaries" movies={documentaries} />
        </section>
      </main> 
     {showModal} && <Modal />
    </div>
  );

}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
const products = await getProducts(payments, {
includePrices: true,
activeOnly: true
  }).then((res) => res).catch((error) => console.log(error.message))

const [
netflixOriginals,
trendingNow,
topRated,
actionMovies,
comedyMovies,
horrorMovies,
romanceMovies,
documentaries,
await Promise.all([
fetch(requests.fetchNetflixOriginals).then((res) => res.json()),
fetch(requests.fetchTrending).then((res) => res.json()),
fetch(requests.fetchTopRated).then((res) => res.json()),
fetch(requests.fetchActionMovies).then((res) => res.json()),
fetch(requests.fetchComedyMovies).then((res) => res.json()),
fetch(requests.fetchHorrorMovies).then((res) => res.json()),
fetch(requests.fetchRomanceMovies).then((res) => res.json()),
fetch(requests.fetchDocumentaries).then((res) => res.json()),
  ]);
return {
props: {
netflixOriginals: netflixOriginals.results,
trendingNow: trendingNow.results,
topRated: topRated.results,
actionMovies: actionMovies.results,
comedyMovies: comedyMovies.results,
horrorMovies: horrorMovies.results,
romanceMovies: romanceMovies.results,
documentaries: documentaries.results,
products
    },
  };
};

export default Home;

What I Tried:

I added error handling for the getProducts call to ensure that it logs any issues.
I attempted to sanitize the products array by converting undefined values to null using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse.
I restarted Firebase multiple times, created a new database, and set up new Stripe products.
I verified that the collection of products exists in my Firebase database.
I confirmed that Firebase is properly attached to my app, as new users are successfully added to the Firebase database upon registration.
Despite these efforts, the serialization error persists, indicating that there might still be an undefined value within the products array.

I expected the getServerSideProps function to fetch the products and other movie data without encountering serialization issues, allowing the products array to be passed to the component without any errors.

So, to fix the issue with the Stripe integration, I created a new file named fetchProducts.js. This file is responsible for fetching products from the Firestore database. I cant post the whole code due the character limit. if anyone has a better solution, pls add it onto this post.

Hello again,
To anyone having similar problems, the issue is caused by the Stripe version and SDK being outdated. Instead, consider using a direct implementation of the API. For guidance, refer to this video: https://youtu.be/xi3F2Zv91UE?t=1455. I am going to close this question now.


Hello everyone,
For anyone encountering similar issues, it seems that the problem
stems from using an outdated version of the Stripe SDK. To resolve
this, I recommend implementing the Stripe API directly rather than
relying on the outdated SDK.
Here’s an outline of the approach you can take:
Fetch Products and Prices: If you still need to fetch product and
price data from Firestore, create your fetchProducts.ts file to
dynamically retrieve this information. Here is the code for fetching
products:
// fetchProducts.ts

    import { db } from '../firebase';
    import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
    
    const fetchProducts = async (): Promise<any[]> => {
      const products: any[] = [];
    
      try {
        const productsCollection = collection(db, 'products');
        const q = query(productsCollection, where('active', '==', true));
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    
        for (const doc of querySnapshot.docs) {
          const productData = doc.data();
          const pricesCollection = collection(doc.ref, 'prices');
          const priceSnap = await getDocs(pricesCollection);
    
          const prices = priceSnap.docs.map((priceDoc) => ({
            id: priceDoc.id,
            ...priceDoc.data(),
          }));
    
          products.push({
            id: doc.id,
            ...productData,
            prices,
          });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching products:', error);
      }
    
      return products;
    };
    
    export default fetchProducts;


Start a Subscription with Stripe Checkout: Use the following code
snippet to start a subscription by creating a new document in the
checkout_sessions collection for the user. The Firestore extension
will update this document with a Stripe Checkout session ID, which you
can use to redirect the user to the checkout page.

import { collection, addDoc, doc, onSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { auth, db } from '../firebase';

const createCheckoutSession = async (priceId: string) => {
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  if (!user) throw new Error('No authenticated user found.');

  const uid = user.uid;

  // Create a checkout session in Firestore
  const col = collection(db, 'customers', uid, 'checkout_sessions');
  const docRef = await addDoc(col, {
    price: priceId,
    success_url: window.location.origin,
    cancel_url: window.location.origin,
  });

  


// Listen for the checkout session to be created and fetch the URL

return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, 'customers', uid, 'checkout_sessions', docRef.id), (snap) => {
      const data = snap.data();
      if (data?.url) {
        unsub();
        resolve(data.url);
      } else if (data?.error) {
        unsub();
        reject(new Error(`An error occurred: ${data.error.message}`));
      }
    });
  });
};

export default createCheckoutSession;


Integrate into Your Component: Use the createCheckoutSession function
within your component to handle the subscription process. Here's an
example of how you might integrate it:

import createCheckoutSession from './path/to/your/createCheckoutSession';

const subscribeToPlan = async (priceId: string) => {
  try {
    const url = await createCheckoutSession(priceId);
    window.location.assign(url);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating checkout session:', error);
  }
};


Additionally, you can refer to this video

https://youtu.be/xi3F2Zv91UE?t=1311

for a visual walkthrough of setting up Stripe Checkout with
Firestore.
I hope this helps resolve the issues you’re facing!
Edit : this is my package.json, I downgraded firebase and stripe, I
did not try it with the latest version, but it should work as
expected, since we dont use the SDK that caused this problem.
package.json

{
"name": "nx-clone",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start",
"lint": "next lint"
},
"dependencies": {
"@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
"@heroicons/react": "^1.0.6",
"@invertase/firestore-stripe-payments": "^0.0.7",
"@mui/material": "^5.15.18",
"@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments": "^0.0.6",
"firebase": "^9.0.0",
"next": "^14.2.3",
"next-transpile-modules": "^10.0.1",
"react-icons": "^5.2.1",
"react-player": "^2.16.0",
"recoil": "^0.7.7",
"tailwind-scrollbar-hide": "^1.1.7"
},
"resolutions": {
"@firebase/firestore": "3.13.0",
"@firebase/auth": "0.23.2",
"@firebase/app": "0.9.13"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@types/node": "^20",
"@types/react": "^18",
"@types/react-dom": "^18",
"autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
"eslint": "^8",
"eslint-config-next": "14.2.3",
"postcss": "^8.4.38",
"tailwind-scrollbar": "^3.1.0",
"tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
"tailwindcss-no-scrollbar": "^1.0.1",
"tailwindcss-textshadow": "^2.1.3",
"typescript": "^5"
}
}

The issue is resolved, and the solution I used is detailed in my accepted answer. For anyone facing similar issues, please refer to my answer for details.
